# Gnome menu with mouse up to the top

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, mouse, menu

I am just starting with Linux. I have noticed that though Gnome has a fixed menu (Gnome panel) at the top of the screen, similarly to Mac OS X, it is impossible to click a menu item after moving the mouse all the way up, to the very edge of the screen. It looks as if there is a one pixel border between the menu and the screen top edge. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: I don't know about this bug as I haven't experienced this in all the versions and distros that I have used before. But if you can't find a way to fix it, you can reach the menu by pressing the [Alt][F1] combo keys, which will open and give focus to the "Applications" menu.

Comment: @Geppettvs D'Constanzo: Sorry, I probably badly expressed myself. I can click the menu items, this is not a problem. The problem is that if the mouse is at the very top of the screen, it is not above the menu any more. As if there was a border of 1 pixel around the menu. When I click the border, the menu items are not clicked. Funny enough: there is the same "border" to the left from the Gnome menu. However, if the mouse is in the top left corner---i.e. both at the left and top borders,---the "Applications" is actually clicked.

Comment: I have just discovered a funny feature. If the active window is not maximized, clicking at the top edge of the screen ("border" above the Gnome menu) maximizes it! I wonder if it is a feature or a bug :)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. And thank you for your self answer. I some weeks ago was looking for a tool like Aero Snap for Ubuntu. Which I give for solved by having your feedback right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. The problem (or, rather, the reason) was that I had enabled Windows 7-like window maximize feature (maximize window by dragging it to the top of the screen), as explained [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/aero-snap-ubuntu-linux.html). Having switched it off, I can now use the Gnome menu with the mouse all the way up and left.

Comment: Glad you found the fix.  I had the same problem with clicking the top-left and top-right pixels of my screen why I set some Mac-like corners in Compiz.